# ¿Cómo encontrar un elemento por index en iOS Appium?

Tags: java, ios, selenium

Tengo este trozo de código que me servía para encontrar un elemento por el index, con el tema de Android no tengo ningún problema, pero mi problema es con iOS porque desde que "IosUIAutomation" quedó obsoleto no encuentro cómo sustituirlo.

Este es mi código:

```
    private void SelectByIndex(LocatorTypesEnum locatorType, String locator, String index, String condition,
            int timeoutForWaitCondition) {
        try {
            element = getElement(locator, locatorType, condition, timeoutForWaitCondition);
            System.out.println("Element: "+element);
            MobileElement listItem = null;
            if (os_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Android")){
                listItem = element.findElement(
                        MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().index(" + Integer.parseInt(index) + ")"));
            } else if (os_name.equalsIgnoreCase("ios")) {
                /*listItem = element.findElement(
                        MobileBy.IosUIAutomation("new UiSelector().index(" + Integer.parseInt(index) + ")"));*/ 
//This is the part I need to replace


            }

            assertNotNull(listItem.getLocation());
            ar = this.setActionResultValues(ar, _takeScreenshotToStep, "", true, false, null);
            listItem.click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
}
            
    }
```

Soy nuevo en este tema, por favor si alguien puede ayudarme, le estaré muy agradecido.

He intentado utilizar "iOSNsPredicateString" pero tampoco ha funcionado porque no encuentra el elemento para el index dado.

```
    else if (os_name.equalsIgnoreCase("ios")) {
   listItem = element.findElement (MobileBy.iOSNsPredicateString ("new UiSelector().index(" + Integer.parseInt(index) + ")"));
}
```

Comment: Hola estas usando appium version 8 ?

Comment: Asi es, estoy usando Appium 8